# Read integers from text file into matrix in c - Access violation

Tags: c, file, matrix, integer

trying to read in from a text file with 10 lines of 10 numbers separated by spaces. I want to directly save each number into a space in the matrix numList.
Really not sure what the problem is with my code, I think it might be because i'm not initializing the matrix correctly or something. Any help appreciated

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    FILE* fpointer = fopen("numbers.txt", "r");
    if (fpointer == NULL) {
        printf("No file found");
        return 1;
    }

    // INITIALISE MATRIX
    char* numList[10][10];
    char  buffer[300];

    // COPY NUMBERS INTO MATRIX
    int i = 0;
    while (fgets(buffer, 300, fpointer)) {
        int j = 0;
        char* p = strtok(buffer, " ");
        while ((p != NULL)&&(j<10)) {
            printf(" %s ",p);

            strcpy(numList[i][j],p);

            p = strtok(NULL, " ");
            j++;
        }
        printf("\n");
        i++;
    }


    printf("\n\n");
    //Print Final Matrix
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
            printf("%s ", numList[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    fclose(fpointer);
    return 0;
}
```

Problem is occurring on the strcpy(numList[i][j],p) function but i'm not sure why.

Output: Exception thrown at 0x7C15EE87 (ucrtbased.dll) in asd.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0xCCCCCCCC.

Comment: `numList[i][j]` is not allocated

Comment: Please add the function heading

Comment: Add the statement `numList[i][j]= malloc(strlen(p)+1);`

Answer (score -1):

No memory is allocated for `numList[i][j]`
You can use `strdup` instead of `strcpy`

```
while (fgets(buffer, 300, fpointer)) {
    int j = 0;
    char* p = strtok(buffer, " ");
    while ((p != NULL)&&(j<10)) {
        printf(" %s ",p);

        numList[i][j] = strdup(p);

        p = strtok(NULL, " ");
        j++;
    }
    printf("\n");
    i++;
}
```